# Xamarin - How to send Push Notifications without using another service

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification

Hi I'm wanting to send push notifications to devices for both iOS and Android. But I am wanting to do it by not using Azure or other Products and services like that. Is this at all possible and if so how would I achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you want to use third party code? I use PushSharp and have had no problems. Simple, easy to use, and open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send you push notifications, you will need to have some sort of server to communicate with Apple's and Google's push services. And presumably if you're sending push notifications, you have some sort of content you need to deliver to the mobile device, which implies you are running a web service somewhere to deliver the content.

The server that handles push notifications can be anything from a box running in your closet to an IaaS virtual machine from a commercial cloud provider. However, your most inexpensive option will likely be Azure Notification Hubs or something similar from another provider.

Answer (score 2):

All push notification architectures require some service, in addition to the platform notification service, to send push notifications. The following diagram (from the Azure docs) shows the basic lifecycle of a notification:

[image: push notification architecture from the Azure docs]

Notice that some backend service has to be there to both keep track of handle assigned to a device by the PNS and also to send the actual notifications. The [free tier in Azure Notification Hubs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/) lets you have up to 500 devices and 1 million pushes before you have to move up to a pay tier. Agree with [jblair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3779829/jblair) that you should at least take a look at Notification Hubs, and there is a [Xamarin quickstart tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-get-started/).

(Full disclosure, I do work at Microsoft on Azure.)

Comment: Hi have been using Azure and was just looking for alternative. I have had a play around with PushSharp but does seem like Azure is the better option.